# Lookup user id by email in slack bot

Tags: jira, webhooks, slack

### Use case

I have JIRA where users can create issues/cards. Whenever a user creates the card, I would like to mention the creator in the slack channel.

I created a slack bot and webhook URL. Added the webhook URL in JIRA and it's sending the message.

Message that will be sent from JIRA

```js
Hi, <#issue> ,

Please look into this issue `{{issue.summary}}`

{{issue.url.customer}}.

Reporter - {{issue.reporter.emailAddress}}
```

JIRA can give me only the reporter email address, but to mention the user in slack i need the user id of slack.

Is there any way we can achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this API : [users.lookupByEmail](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail)

 you can use this to fetch userId, 
but given that you are using just Webhook URL, you'll need to implement additional code.